# How to find a specific curve if the initial value is not given?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

**Question:**

Let $y(x)$ be the solution of the differential equation

$x\cdot ln(x)\dfrac{dy}{dx}+y=2x\cdot ln(x)$, $x\ge1$.

Find $y(e)$.

**Answer**: $y(e) = 2$

**Problem:**

So I understand that this can be converted into a simple linear differential equation and found that the solution is:

$y\cdot ln(x)=2(x\cdot ln(x) - x) + C$

This is a family of curves. However for solving the question, I need a specific curve out of all these.
What I don't understand is how how do I find that particular curve  as the initial value of the function is not given.

Comment: y(e) = C.......

Comment: @WilliamElliot Nah. Edited the question.

Comment: Note that, evaluating the original equation with $x=1$, you find $y(1)=0$

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo So there is only one possible solution for this equation. But how is it possible if I am not given the initial values for the DE.  Because the whole family satisfies the given DE.

Comment: "give the initial value" is relative  because, for example in this case, the initial value is given implicitely. Other case: solve $y(x)=1+\int\limits_{0}^x y(t) dt$

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo If they did not gave me the statement $x\ge 1$, that would make the question unsolvable, right?

Comment: hmm no, without conditions you must consider the maximal domain. In this case $\mathbb{R}^+$, and because $1\in\mathbb{R}^+$, is an equivalent problem

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo Yes, but then I can counter your argument that $y(1)$ is not defined as 1 is not in the domain of the function.

Comment: why is not in the domain? If the problem were with $x\geq 2$ for example, you can extend it to $\mathbb{R}^+$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87670/discussion-between-harshit54-and-martin-vacas-vignolo).

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo $x=1$ is a singular point of the equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that the answer $y(e) = 2$ is wrong if the question is stated like this.

You have already found the correct general solution of the first-order linear ODE, with one constant of integration $C \in \mathbb{R}$. From this you do indeed get $y(e) = C$ as William Elliot has pointed out. Therefore, you can obtain any value for $y(e)$, depending on the value of $C$.

**The reason why the particular solution with $C=2$ is of interest is that it is the only solution of this ODE *for which the (right-sided) limit as $x \searrow 1$ is finite.***

For the general solution $y(x) = \frac{2x(\ln(x)-1)+C}{\ln(x)}$, $C \in \mathbb{R}$, we have
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \searrow 1} y(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
-\infty, C < 2\\
0, C = 2\\
\infty, C > 2
\end{array}
\right..
\end{equation}
Therefore, *if we assume that the right-sided limit of $y(x)$ is finite as $x$ approaches $1$,* then there remains only the particular solution with $C=2$, which satisfies $y(e) = 2$.

But this assumption needs to be added to the question, otherwise the answer is wrong.